# Disable HTML escaping in erb templates

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, escaping, erb

In a Rails 3 application I have a domain class where one attribute stores pure HTML content (it's a blog app, the domain class is Post).

In the ERB templates, I need to display the content of the attribute as it was formmated, with the HTML tags in place. But, Rails is escaping all HTML tags! How can I disable this behaviour for this class attribute?

Example:

```
somePost = Post.new
somePost.content = "<strong> Hi, i'm here! </strong>"
```

In the erb template:

```
<%= somePost.content %>
```

The HTML generated is escaped:

```
&lt;strong&gt; Hi, i'm here! &lt;/strong&gt;
```

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Try using `raw(somePost.content)`. Alternatively, `somePost.content.html_safe`.

Comment: IMHO raw is a little safer than .html_safe because raw(nil) writes "", where nil.html_safe results in an exception.

Comment: .html_safe is an implementation detail of Rails and was never meant for Public-facing API. The `raw(string)` method should be used instead. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/rubyonrails-core/T9N5wexIg80

Comment: raw is wrapped in html_safe. They do the same thing except raw also calls .to_s.

Answer (score 61):

Use `raw(string)`, as [described in the release notes](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/3_0_release_notes.html#action-view).

> #### 7.4.3 Other Changes
>
> You no longer need to call h(string) to escape HTML output, it is on by default in all view templates. If you want the unescaped string, call raw(string).

Basically, where you did

```
<%=h @model.attr %>
```

before you can now use

```
<%= @model.attr %>
```

and where you did *that* before you can now use

```
<%=raw @model.attr %>
```

Answer (score 37):

Using a double equals means the result is not escaped...

```
<%== somePost.content %>
```

See this SO question about it - [What does <%== %> do in rails erb?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13142326/what-does-do-in-rails-erb)

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for, not the accepted one :) This is basically equivalent to [using `!=`](http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.REFERENCE.html#unescaping_html) (instead of just `=`) in HAML templates.