# How to make html code in erb tag not escaped

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, erb, html-escape

I have some simple erb code in one of my views in a rails project.

`<%= comment.body %>`

I'd like the html tags in the comment.body to be preserved as they have formatting information. I've verified that the text is saved in the database properly like

`<b>hello</b>`

However it turns out on the page to be `<b>hello</b>` not **hello** as I expect.

How could this be? I'm not using `<%= h` to escape the html code.

How do I make it not escaping? I'm using rails 3. Does this matter?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Disable HTML escaping in erb templates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4699497/disable-html-escaping-in-erb-templates)

Comment: Quick answer: Rails 3 calls `h` by default. This is a duplicate question though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rails 3 now automatically escapes your output.

To unescape the text and use the actual tags, use `raw(...)`:

```
<%= raw(comment.body) %>
```

However, be careful with this, as it will allow any tags, including scripts (potentially malicious). A safer option might be to have users use markdown-formatted text or something similar, rather than allowing raw HTML tags.

Comment: Thanks for a clear answer and the extra useful information. I tried tinymce hammer plugin, and it is filtering out tags such as <script>, <blink> etc. Feature wise it is pretty neat. How well is it accepted in terms of safety?

Answer (score 5):

You can also use sanitize.

```
<%= sanitize(comment.body) %>
```

sanitize will leave html code but escape javascript.