# Rails 3 - Problems with raw and html_safe

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Using the raw and html_safe methods with Rails 3.0.10 and I am still unable to unescape the html and get it to display as **Content** instead of `<strong>Content</strong>`.

`@object.property.html_safe` gives me `<strong>Some content</strong>`

`<%= raw(@object.property) %>` also gives me `<strong>Some content</strong>`

I have seen these posts and tried to implement their fixes:

- [raw vs. html_safe vs. h to unescape html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4251284/raw-vs-html-safe-vs-h-to-unescape-html)
- [Disable HTML escaping in erb templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4699497/disable-html-escaping-in-erb-templates)
- [How to make html code in erb tag not escaped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6367096/how-to-make-html-code-in-erb-tag-not-escaped)

I have also watched the Ryan Bates Railscasts episode about xss protection:  http://railscasts.com/episodes/204-xss-protection-in-rails-3?view=comments

I created a helper method based on his example called **safe** where I made sure the string content had the html_safe method applied:

```
def safe(content)
    "#{content}".html_safe
end
```

Then I called it on my model:  `safe(@object.property)`

Still the content is not displaying as expected.

I have also tried using the **sanitize** method, but to no avail.

What could be causing this?

Comment: What output are you expecting, exactly? Your first two code examples do exactly what they're supposed to. Do you really mean you want it escaped? (e.g. `&lt;strong&gt;Some content...`)

Comment: Just trying to get the actual html to display - not the tags.  Updated question to be specific.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok, looks like I've got it working now.

Looked in the Ruby docs and found the **CGI** class and the **unescapeHTML** method.

I was using a rich text editor in a form to save text to the database.  Apparently since the html was sent to the database as escaped, I needed to undo the escaping and then call html_safe on it.

This is how it appears in the database:  `&lt;strong&gt;howdy&lt;/strong&gt;`

I applied that to my helper method, and now the html displays as html instead of tags.

```
def safe(content)
  "#{ CGI::unescapeHTML(content) }".html_safe
end
```

This works, but if there is a better way to handle this scenario I'm open to suggestions.

**Update**

---

I was experimenting with Rails helper methods to try and prevent the text from being saved to the database as escaped (which would solve my problem since then I wouldn't have to un-escape it).

As it turns out, the rich text editor that I am using is encoding the html - you have to pass it a property of `encoded: false` within the javascripts object literal notation.

So, if you are like me and pulling your hair out trying to find out why Rails is saving text to the database as encoded - you may actually need to tweak configuration on the rich text editor itself.

Now I can remove the CGI class and just use this as a helper:

```
def safe(content)
  "#{ content }".html_safe
end
```

Hopefully someone else will find this helpful too.

Comment: The better way to handle it is to not store escaped HTML in the DB if you intend to render it unescaped `:)`.

Comment: I've tried using the raw and html_safe methods on the form's text_area, but it still strores it as escaped.  How would I prevent the form from saving it as escaped?

Comment: Perhaps make another question about that issue?

Answer (score 0):

Here is another option, and perhaps the better one. Use the following snippet.

```
plain_text = strip_tags(html_input)
```

Here is the links to docs.[enter link description here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/)