# Output HTML in a RJ ERB template

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, prototypejs

This might be something silly really, but I can't get it to work at all...

I have vacation.js.erb which generates some javascript to update a page when the ajax call is done. The source of the file looks like this:

```
$('semantic').replace('<div id="semantic"></div>');
<%
    html = '<table class="ajax">'
    html += "<tr><td>EU - 27</td><td>#{@eu.value.value} days</td></tr>"
    html += "<tr><td>#{@source.location.value}</td><td>#{@source.value.value } days></td></tr>" unless @source.location.value.blank?
    html += "<tr><td>#{@cv.country.name}</td><td>No Data Available</td></tr>" if @source.location.value.blank?
    html += "<tr><td>#{@target.location.value}</td><td>#{@target.value.value } days></td></tr>" unless @target.location.value.blank?
    html += "<tr><td>#{@vacancy.country.name}</td><td>#{@target.value.value } days></td></tr>" if @target.location.value.blank?
    html += "</table>"
%>
$('semantic').insert('<%= escape_javascript(html) %>');
```

I can cleary go through the code with the browser, but the last line is causing me troubles. It encodes the stuff in html to html entities, and I don't want this, cause it breaks the javascript. The response in Fiddler looks like this:

> $('semantic').replace('');
>   $('semantic').insert('<table
>   class=\"ajax\"><tr><td>EU -
>   27</td><td>28
>   days</td></tr><tr><td>gb</td><td>No
>   Data Available</td></tr><tr><td>United
>   Kingdom</td><td>29
>   days></td></tr></table>');

How can I prevent the page from encoding the html variable?
I tried using ***<%! html %>*** but that returns nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

fixed it, the solution was

```
$('semantic').replace('<div id="semantic"></div>');
<%
    html = '<table class="ajax">'
    html += "<tr><td>EU - 27</td><td>#{@eu.value.value} days</td></tr>"
    html += "<tr><td>#{@source.location.value}</td><td>#{@source.value.value } days></td></tr>" unless @source.location.value.blank?
    html += "<tr><td>#{@cv.country.name}</td><td>No Data Available</td></tr>" if @source.location.value.blank?
    html += "<tr><td>#{@target.location.value}</td><td>#{@target.value.value } days></td></tr>" unless @target.location.value.blank?
    html += "<tr><td>#{@vacancy.country.name}</td><td>#{@target.value.value } days</td></tr>" if @target.location.value.blank?
    html += "</table>"
%>
$('semantic').insert('<%=raw html  -%>');
```

Found the solution here: [Disable HTML escaping in erb templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4699497/disable-html-escaping-in-erb-templates)