# "Could not concatenate to the buffer because it is not html safe" during rspec test with Capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

Recently I am seeing tests using Rails 3 intermittently fail with the following error:

```
Failure/Error: visit some_path
ActionView::Template::Error:
  Could not concatenate to the buffer because it is not html safe.
```

The failures appears to be non-deterministic.

Can anyone suggest what could be causing it?

Comment: I'm seeing a similar issue - in production - Did you find the cause of this problem?

Comment: I'm afraid we never got anywhere, and I've since left the project :(

Answer (score 0):

the view file on some_path has a field which is returning a field which is using `<%= %>`instead of `<%=h %>` ?

Comment: I don't believe that will solve the problem in, because `h` is included implicitly in Rails 3 (which I apologize for neglecting to mention, question updated), unless I am mistaken, as per: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4699531/21115

Comment: ah ok, sorry i had to guess at a version. all i can think at this point is that the buffer is reaching a limit which is ending in a bad way, if the file it's trying to buffer particularly large or something?

Comment: No, there is nothing atypical about the views which are causing this, indeed it is being emitted on a variety of views which have nothing (apparently) in common.