# Rails embed html tag inside an erb tag?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I'm trying to do this:

```
<%= <h1>Products Purchased </h1> if  params[:status].nil? || params[:status] == Order.statuses[0]  %>

<%= "<h1>Products Sent </h1>" if  params[:status].nil? || params[:status] == Order.statuses[1]  %>
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Disable HTML escaping in erb templates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4699497/disable-html-escaping-in-erb-templates)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to use .html_safe to output HTML tags from a ruby string:

```
<%= "<h1>Products Sent </h1>".html_safe if params[:status].nil? || params[:status] == Order.statuses[1]  %>
```

But you can do the following, more readable:

```
<% if params[:status].nil? || params[:status] == Order.statuses[1] %>
  <h1>Products Sent</h1>
<% end %>
```

Comment: How do you embed ruby in an html string for an <a> tag? I'm trying to do this => <a data-gallery <%= video_tag(user.video, :type='video/mp4', :poster => video.poster %>

Comment: @Jackson_Sandland You can use string interpolation to execute ruby code inside a string: `"Hello #{user.name}!"` But in your case you should use the `link_to` helper like this: `link_to 'title of link', 'path_to_go', data: { galery: video_tag(user.video, type: 'video/mp4', poster: video.poster) }`

Answer (score 1):

Here alternative is:

```
<h1>
  <%= 'Products Purchased' if cond1 %>
  <%= 'Products Sent'      if cond2 %>
</h1>
```

Or, you can use `content_tag` helper method for any HTML tag:

```
<%= content_tag(:h1, 'Products Purchased') if cond1 %>
<%= content_tag(:h1, 'Products Sent') if cond2 %>
```

Where, cond1 and cond2 are "params[:status].nil? || ..." as you specify

(I wonder what happens when both cond1 and cond2 are false, but I think it is out of this topic)