# Dynamically Render HTML stored in Model

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, haml

I want to take some Rails models passed into a view and render them.

e.g.

In the controller

```
@stories = Story.all
```

In the view

```
$('.story-text').html("#{raw @stories[0].story_text}");
```

But the HTML string contains `"` and `'`. The HTML is thus not contained entirely in a string and the Javascript fails to run.

e.g. it becomes

```
$('.story-text').html("<img src="/example.jpg" />");
```

Which causes an error.

How can I accomplish this? Is there triple quotes like in Python that I can use in Javascript?

**EDIT** Example of `@stories[0].story_text`

```
<p>This is some example text</p><img src="/example.jpg" />
```

It is stored in the database as a `text` type

Comment: Please post your controller code to show how Story.all is populated.

Comment: post an example of `@stories[0].story_text`

Comment: Story.all is populated through a form using CKEditor. The controller is literally only doing `@stories = Story.all` I added an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than `raw`, use [`escape_javascript`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/JavaScriptHelper.html#method-i-escape_javascript) to escape your string suitably for embedding in javascript. It is aliased to `j`, so this in your Haml view:

```
$('.story-text').html("#{j @stories[0].story_text}");
```

results in this javascript being generated:

```javascript
$('.story-text').html("<p>This is some example text<\/p><img src=\"/example.jpg\" />");
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for [HTMLEntities](http://htmlentities.rubyforge.org/)

Comment: I don't quite understand how this would work? I would encode/escape the HTML in my controller and decode it with Javascript in my view? Wouldn't I face the same problem with the quotation marks when decoding?  Could you add an example relating to my problem?

Comment: why are you doing the output in Javascript? It should be in view script

Comment: Can you dynamically insert HTML with view script? I want to click a link and have the HTML inserted into an element

Comment: alright, I understand. Are you fetching the model data via AJAX?

Comment: No, they're all being passed by the controller to the view at rendering

Comment: view meaning view script? how is it going to the JS?

Comment: It's my `.html.haml` file, I'm using some Javascript there

Comment: can you try this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4699497/disable-html-escaping-in-erb-templates