# How to display AsciiDoc in RoR view with AsciiDoctor Gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, asciidoc, asciidoctor

In my rails view I use

```
<%= Asciidoctor.render '*This* is http://asciidoc.org[AsciiDoc]!' %>
```

I expected to get

```
<div class="paragraph"> <p><strong>This</strong> is 
<a href="http://asciidoc.org">AsciiDoc</a>!</p> </div>
```

but instead of that I get (in page source code)

```
&lt;div class=&quot;paragraph&quot;&gt;
&lt;p&gt;&lt;strong&gt;This&lt;/strong&gt; is &lt;a href=&
quot;http://asciidoc.org&quot;&gt;AsciiDoc&lt;/a&gt;!&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;/div&gt;
```

What am I doing wrong? How to display asciidoc converted to html not literally with all `<tags>` as now?

Comment: It looks like it's working, but maybe web is encoding the asciidoctor output?

Comment: Yeah, but how to get effect I want?

Comment: Looks like any of the answers at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4699497/disable-html-escaping-in-erb-templates will fix the escaping problem.

Comment: LightGuard - Thank you so much :)