# Is there a helper for creating erb tags?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb

I've added the following method to the module `ApplicationHelper` in `app/helpers/application_helper.rb`:

```
def autofill_inputs model, index, fkey
 value ="#{model}_#{index}"
 text_field_tag nil, nil, :data => {value: value, source: "<%= #{model.pluralize}_path(:json) %>"}
end
```

I invoke it in `app/views/transactions/new.html.erb`:

```
<%= autofill_inputs "transaction", 0, "entity" %>
```

No doubt in pursuit of injection prevention, the `<input>` in the generated HTML the angle brackets are escaped out:

```
<input type="text" id="" data-value="transaction_0" data-source="&lt;%= transactions_path(:json) %&gt;" />
```

is there an "erb tag helper"?

Comment: Take a look at this question ... I'm not 100% sure, but I believe you can use the `raw` method: `raw( text_field_tag(...))`

Comment: I just noticed there is an even cleaner version, use `<%==` instead of raw: `<%== autofill_inputs ... %>`

Comment: Oops, I also noticed I forgot to [link](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4699497/398606) to the other question :)