# How to output greek symbols in html using ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to take as input text that takes the full greek name for a letter and displays it as a single greek letter. e.g. take 'alpha' and replace it with α.

My code looks like this

```
def name(y1)
    "&#{y1};"
end
```

with the output put into a html page using erb, i.e.

```
<%= name('alpha') %>
```

but the result is displayed in the html as `&alpha;` . How do I make it display α?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on: [Disable HTML escaping in erb templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4699497/disable-html-escaping-in-erb-templates)
The escaping occurs in the ERB so you need to specify that the string is safe in the ERB.

Try this:

```
def name(y1)
    "&#{y1};"
end

<%= name('alpha').html_safe %>
```