# Character "d' " becoming " d&#39; " when displayed

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, character-encoding, utf

So I got this address `7 rue la Tour d'Auvergne` from an API request in AJAX.

But when I feed it to an input in my view or even just display it like this

**get_adress.js.erb**

```
alert('<%= @sellsy_address.address %>')
$('#address').val('<%= @sellsy_address.address unless @sellsy_address.blank? %>');
```

I got this `7 rue la Tour d&#39;Auvergne`

Any idea on how I can manage to keep the `d'` as it is ? I tried to encode or decode it in different ways but no results.

Thanks in advance

**EDIT**

If I use raw of html_safe, my js.erb just does not load at all anymore

Comment: tried `unescape()` ?

Comment: did you try unescape? https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_unescape.asp

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable HTML escaping in erb templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4699497/disable-html-escaping-in-erb-templates)

Comment: unescape() is obsolete. It has been replaced by decodeURI so I tried `$('#address').val(decodeURI('<%= @sellsy_address.address %>'));` but it doesn't work either

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `html_safe` along with `escape_javascript` (or `j`), like this:

```
alert('<%= j @sellsy_address.address.html_safe %>');
```

Alternatively, you could skip `j` but change single quotes to double quotes, like this:

```
alert("<%= @sellsy_address.address.html_safe %>");
```

> If I use raw of html_safe, my js.erb just does not load at all anymore

That is because you get a syntax error due to the `'` in `7 rue la Tour d'Auvergne` being inside single quotes. Check the following examples;

**Single quotes, without `escape_javascript` (or `j`)**

```
alert('<%= @sellsy_address.address.html_safe %>');

//generated code:
alert('7 rue la Tour d'Auvergne');
```

As you can see, the alert gets the string `'7 rue la Tour d'` and then expects a closing parenthesis (`)`), so you get an error an no alert is displayed.

**Single quotes, with `escape_javascript` (or `j`)**

```
alert('<%= j @sellsy_address.address.html_safe %>');

//generated code:
alert('7 rue la Tour d\'Auvergne');
```

Now the `'` has been escaped and is no longer a closing quote, so the alert is correctly displayed.

**Double quotes, without `escape_javascript` (or `j`)**

```
alert("<%= @sellsy_address.address.html_safe %>");

//generated code:
alert("7 rue la Tour d'Auvergne");
```

This time `'` needs no escaping since the string is enclosed between double quotes ('" "') which avoids any conflict with single quotes (`'`).

Comment: It works ! Without the j my js.erb doesn't even load and the alert never pop. What does the j stand for ?

Comment: @LRP Check updated answer to clarify your questions.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for taking the time to clarify.